# Debug and properties loading

Tags: c#, debugging, properties, breakpoints

I have an object that represents a record of a table in my database, for example 'Project'.

My User class has different properties which are the records of other tables, for example, 'Client' or 'Accountancy'. Those also have properties to related tables.

Each of these properties returns a local value (already loaded) if not null, and there is no loaded information, it generates a request to get this value from database.

My issue is the following : when I set a breakpoint, and check the object in the debug window, it loads automatically all the values of the properties, and so, requests the database.

With this scenario, I cannot have a precise and static snapshot of my object at the moment.

Is there a way, in code, not to go through this part of code if in debug window ?
For instance, something like that:

```
public MyBaseObject GetProperty<T>(string columnName_, string alias_ = null) where T : MyBaseObject, new()
{
    var ret = GetExtract<T>(columnName_, alias_);

    // if the data are loaded
    if (ret.Id != null)
        return ret;

    // Fake boolean I would like
    if(InDebugWindowAfterAbreakPointForInstance) 
        return ret;
    else 
        ret = LoadFromDatabase<T>(columnName_, alias_)
    return ret;
}
```

I've found different attributes with the debugger, like the `DebuggerStepperBoundaryAttribute`, but nothing that could do something like that.

Comment: Why is this tagged with both C# and D? Please remove the tag for the language you are not using.

Answer (score 0):

In situations like this the only way I know of is to use a [`DebuggerTypeProxy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8eyd8zc.aspx) for each of your types then in that proxy have it access the backing field directly instead of going through the property that causes the database lookup to happen.

Here is a simple example program.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new Client();
        Debugger.Break();
        Debugger.Break();
    }
}

[DebuggerTypeProxy(typeof(ClientDebugView))]
public class Client : MyBaseObject
{
    private string _firstName;
    private string _lastName;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            if (_firstName == null)
                _firstName = GetProperty<string>("FirstName");

            return _firstName;
        }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(_firstName, value))
                return;
            _firstName = value;
            UpdateDatabase(_firstName, "FirstName");
        }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get
        {
            if (_lastName == null)
                _lastName = GetProperty<string>("LastName");

            return _lastName;
        }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(_lastName, value))
                return;
            _lastName = value;
            UpdateDatabase(_lastName, "LastName");
        }
    }

    internal class ClientDebugView : MyBaseObjectDebugView
    {
        private readonly Client _client;

        public ClientDebugView(Client client)
            : base(client)
        {
            _client = client;
        }

        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return _client._firstName; }
        }

        public string LastName
        {
            get { return _client._lastName; }
        }
    }
}

[DebuggerTypeProxy(typeof(MyBaseObjectDebugView))]
public class MyBaseObject
{
    private Guid? _id;

    public Guid? Id
    {
        get
        {
            if (_id == null)
                _id = GetProperty<Guid?>("Id");

            return _id;
        }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(_id, value))
                return;
            _id = value;
            UpdateDatabase(_id, "Id");
        }
    }

    //Fake loading data from a database.
    protected T GetProperty<T>(string columnName)
    {
        object ret = null;
        switch (columnName)
        {
            case "Id":
                ret = Guid.NewGuid();
                break;
            case "LastName":
                ret = "Smith";
                break;
            case "FirstName":
                ret = "John";
                break;
            default:
                ret = null;
                break;
        }

        return (T)ret;
    }

    protected void UpdateDatabase<T>(T id, string s)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    internal class MyBaseObjectDebugView
    {
        private readonly MyBaseObject _baseObject;

        public MyBaseObjectDebugView(MyBaseObject baseObject)
        {
            _baseObject = baseObject;
        }

        public Guid? Id
        {
            get { return _baseObject._id; }
        }
    }
}
```

If you view the `client` object in the debugger you will see it leaves the backing fields `null` between the two breakpoints unless you open the "Raw View" at the first breakpoint.

[image]